# How to import modules from packages in parent dicrectory in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have difficulties understanding where Python searches for packages and modules. Consider the following directory structure:

```
.
├── pkg
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── module.py
└── scripts
    ├── __init__.py
    └── join.py
```

Where all `__init__.py` files are empty, `pkg/module.py` is:

```
############################################################
# File Name : module.py
############################################################

def method(*args):
    return ', '.join(*args)
```

and `scripts/join.py` is:

```
############################################################
# File Name : join.py
############################################################

import os
import sys

from pkg import module


def join(*args):
    print(module.method(args))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    join(*sys.argv[1:])
    sys.exit(os.EX_OK)
```

Now, if I run an interactive python session from the root directory.  I can import `scripts.join` and run the method `join` without problems:

```
>>> from scripts.join import join
>>> join('a', 'B', 'c', 'D')
a, B, c, D
```

However, if I want to run `join` directly from command line I get import errors:

```
$ python3 scripts/join.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/join.py", line 11, in <module>
        from pkg import module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg'
```

Surprisingly if I move `join.py` to the root directory it can be invoked as a script:

```
$ cp scripts/join.py .
$ python3 join.py a b C d E
a, b, C, d, E
```

So I was wondering what's the difference between importing inside interactive session and inside a script.  Also how will I be able to keep `join.py` inside `scripts/` directory (while being able to invoke it from command line without the need for an interactive Python session)?

---

**UPDATE**: I realize that if I tweak `sys.path` in `scripts/join.py` the problem disappears:

```
############################################################
# File Name : join.py
############################################################

import os
import sys

sys.path.append('')

from pkg import module


def join(*args):
    print(module.method(args))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    join(*sys.argv[1:])
    sys.exit(os.EX_OK)
```

Now I can run:

```
$ python3 scripts/join.py a b c d 
a, b, c, d
```

A similar solution is also proposed in the answers.

I wonder if such a tweak is safe or there is a more Pythonic way solution? 
For example, obviously if the scripts is invoked from any other directory it will not work.  Is there any more explicit way to ask Python to import `pkg` from the parent directory?  (One possibility would be to append the path relative to the path of `__file__` in the script to `sys.path`)

I tried adding a `__init__.py` in the root directory and importing like

```
from ..pkg import module
```

But in that case I always get

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because python will try to import the folder(or py file) from current folder(if not find ,it will try to import the module you have installed).That's why if you put `join.py` to root folder,it can run normally.

```
.
├── pkg
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── module.py
└── scripts
    ├── __init__.py
    └── join.py
```

If you want to use `from pkg import module` in `join.py`:

In your `join.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..") # python will try to find the module in his parent folder
from pkg import module
```

---

In [python document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path):

> sys.path:
>   A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default.

At first,it only have two paths to import `sys.argv[0]` and `__file__`.(include python folder in system PATH).After use `sys.path.append("..")`,there will be three paths can be imported.

I think only you have many file which have the same names will cause some problm.

Comment: Thanks.  I also realize that modifying `sys.path` is a workaround.  (Your solution is better than mine as it explicitly says where to look for `pkg`.)   But I wonder if that's a safe workaround?

Answer (score -1):

You need\want to import the function method from the file pkg\module.py.
So your import must look like :

from pkg.module import method

Comment: Whether you import as `from pkg.module import method` or `from pkg import module` is irrelevant here.  The problem is that Python does not find `pkg` or `module`.

Comment: Oh yes, my fault. I read the Folder structur wrong. The sys.append() is the correct way.